# can I use ajax datatable in Django with runtime custom query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, datatable

I really want to use datatable for big data with runtime custom query .I have tried [django-datatable](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable) but seem , it have only static custom query. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at django-datatable; the only thing it seems to do if provide a template tag to render entire DB tables to HTML responses.

```
{% load table_tags %}
...
{% render_table people %}
```

If you want custom DB queries in django, the normal way is to use the ORM, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from models import Person
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
...
def some_view(...):
    a_people = Person.objects.filter(name__startswith="A")
    return render_to_response(<template>, context={"people":a_people})

// HTML template
...
{% for person in people %}
<tr><td>{{ person.id }}</td><td>{{ person.name }</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

This allows you all freedom to define a dynamic DB query in your python code.